# Python check user id in json file Python from strings

Tags: python, json, discord.py

I don't really know how to explain, so I will explain what I'm going to do.

1. `.profile <GrowID>`, Insert GrowID that is in the json file.
2. If GrowID in the file, open the user data

Here is what I have right now

Command Template

```py
@client.command(aliases=["p"])
async def profile(ctx, GrowID=None):
  with open('account.json', 'r') as f:
    account = json.load(f)

  if GrowID == None:
    user = ctx.author

  elif not GrowID == None:
    user = client.get_user(GrowID.user_id)

  if str(user.id) in account:
    # <Codes>
```

My data in `account.json`

```py
{
    "811510359289495572": {
        "Premium": false,
        "GrowID": "Dec7h7alker",
        "Character": "Default",
        "Level": 1,
        "XP": 0,
        "XPLevel": 150,
        "Gems": 0,
        "World Locks": 0,
        "Diamond Locks": 0,
        "Growtokens": 0
    }
}
```

Command to add the data

```py
@client.command()
async def start(ctx):
        with open('account.json', 'r') as f:
          account = json.load(f)
        user = ctx.author

        if str(user.id) in account:
                await ctx.send("Your account has already existed!")

        elif str(user.id) not in account:
                account[str(user.id)] = {}
                account[str(user.id)]["Premium"] = False
                account[str(user.id)]["GrowID"] = user.name
                account[str(user.id)]["Character"] = "Default"
                account[str(user.id)]["Level"] = 1
                account[str(user.id)]["XP"] = 0
                account[str(user.id)]["XPLevel"] = 150
                account[str(user.id)]["Gems"] = 0
                account[str(user.id)]["World Locks"] = 0
                account[str(user.id)]["Diamond Locks"] = 0
                account[str(user.id)]["Growtokens"] = 0

                with open('account.json', 'w') as f:
                        json.dump(account, f, indent=4)

    # <codes (not needed cuz its just sending message)>
```

There you go

Comment: And what now? Does it not work? Do you do not know how to start? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: I want the input GrowID to open the specified user data then the bot will send message of the user's data account.

`user = client.get_user(GrowID.user_id)`  doesn't work

Comment: `GrowID : discord.Member = None` would make more sense, if you ask me.

Comment: Not working, remember that its not mentioning a user, see what is GrowID in the json file.

Comment: How do you add the data, please share the code.

Comment: There you go, I have edited it.

Comment: You have so many functions and none of them have been provided, it's hard to help you.... Why don't you just query the data like in your `elif str(user.id) not in account or inventory:` statement? This obviously works. Try to use `print` statements and see where to bot gets stuck.

Comment: I have removed the functions, there are the important parts I guess. While waiting I'll use the `print` statements.

Comment: The bot just gets stuck at `user = client.get_user(GrowID.user_id)`
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'user_id'

Nothing else

Comment: So what is `user_id`?

Comment: As I said, I don't really know what to do, I was trying to check the user id with the user's  `GrowID` in their data. If the user id is inside the data, then the bot sends message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really don't understand where the problem is, because as already mentioned in the comments you can use your already existing code to retrieve data from the user.

But for that we first assume that `GrowID` depends on `discord.Member`, otherwise it won't work.

**Then we build our command on top of that:**

```py
@client.command(aliases=["p"])
async def profile(ctx, GrowID: discord.Member = None):
    with open('channel.json', 'r') as f:
        account = json.load(f) # Load account

        if GrowID == None:
            user = ctx.author
            await ctx.send(account[str(user.id)]) # Retrieve and send data

        else:
            user1 = client.get_user(GrowID.id) # Get the ID of the named user.
            await ctx.send(account[str(user1.id)]) # Send data of the account
```

**You will then be sent the following about the user:**

```py
{'Premium': False, 'GrowID': 'Dec7h7alker', 'Character': 'Default', 'Level': 1, 'XP': 0, 'XPLevel': 150, 'Gems': 0, 'World Locks': 0, 'Diamond Locks': 0, 'Growtokens': 0}
```

To make this more user friendly then your knowledge is needed, because this has nothing to do with the question anymore.

**How the command works:**

[image]

Comment: @XiaoPoor If you can explain your problem a bit better I may be able to also edit my answer. Is the `GrowID` something you have access to? Do you want to look for that and receive data, based on the `GrowID` which is the `user.name`?

Comment: Ah I just read your comment. I have no problems for now I guess, I have fixed my code.